# How can I change the ForeColor of all labels on a form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, label

Is it possible to change the `ForeColor` of all the labels on a form at runtime, including the form which is yet to be called? So that all the labels have the same color throughout the app.

Comment: Ok, you just walk the whole form and it's children for controls. Meanwhile, you check whether each control has the Forecolor property. If it does then just set it.

Comment: Better yet, just let the labels inherit their `ForeColor` property from the **`Form`** that they're placed on. This is one of those special "ambient" properties in WinForms, where child controls automatically pick up the setting from their parents, as long as the property hasn't been explicitly set for the child control. This way, you don't have to bother looping through all the labels, but they'll still have the same `ForeColor` as all the other labels on your form.

Comment: @Cody Brilliant idea, I am gonna use this :)

Comment: Apparently the [documentation for the `ForeColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx) mentions ambient properties explicitly. This is one of those things that definitely makes your life easier, especially in your situation where you want all the labels to have the *same* colors. You're probably already using this for the `BackColor` without even realizing it.

Comment: @Cody , is this a new feature of VS 2010 ?

Comment: Nope. Been there since the original version of .NET. Surely you've noticed it in the designer? If you add a label to a form with a custom background and foreground color, the label automatically inherits those properties? They key is not messing with the properties on the label control. You're allowed to override the ambient properties, but when you do, they'll always follow your override rather than inheriting from their parent.

Comment: @Cody Looks like vb.net is your favorite  language , you know a lot :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to loop through all of the Form's controls looking for labels. Controls can have child controls so you want to do this recursively:

```
Private Sub UpdateLabelFG(ByVal controls As ControlCollection, ByVal fgColor As Color)
    If controls Is Nothing Then Return
    For Each C As Control In controls
        If TypeOf C Is Label Then DirectCast(C, Label).ForeColor = fgColor
        If C.HasChildren Then UpdateLabelFG(C.Controls, fgColor)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    UpdateLabelFG(Me.Controls, Color.Red)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is as trivial as you might think.  It's easy enough to cycle through all of the controls on a particular form and set the forecolor.  But if you have multiple forms open and set the forecolor in one form; getting all forms to change color is going to be a problem.

I'd say, create your own Form class that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form; use this new form throughout your application.  Add a private sub that takes in the color and loops through the form's controls, setting the label forecolor to the desired color (see Chris Haas's post for an excellent example of this).

Then create a singleton ColorManager class.  The application as a whole will only ever have one foreground color.  ColorManager should have a public event that is fired when the color is changed and a 'SetColor' function (or property however you like) that you will use to set the color.

Then, going back to your form class, you add the event handler for the ColorManager's change color event.

Now any form can set the application-wide forecolor and all open forms will respond to that event and set their color appropriately.

Comment: You can cycle through `Application.OpenForms` if you need to update every open form. It won't fix forms opened after this is called, of course, but the OP didn't ask about that luckily.